# Pulling 3rd party table data into array/json

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl, xpath

I am trying to get this external table data into an array/JSON using PHP. I was able to do it using XPath and counting td etc, however, the data changes a little weekly and screws everything up...Is there a good way to pull this info and use conditional statements to show the appropriate value according to the player's name? Here is the link to the table [See Here](http://www.leagueleader.net/sharedreport.php?operatorid=98&code=1928e435-8dbe-450f-8bca-74f603f892f0)

I would like to get something like

```
Player name:
    GAMES:   
    MPR:
    PPR:
Player name:
    GAMES:   
    MPR:
    PPR:
etc...
```

If anyone could give me a hand or point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it very much! This is driving me nuts i'll even pay if necessary.

Thank you!

Here is my current code

```
$urll = 'http://www.leagueleader.net/sharedreport.php?operatorid=98&code=1928e435-8dbe-450f-8bca-74f603f892f0';

$options = array (
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0", // something like Firefox 
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
);

$curl = curl_init($urll);
curl_setopt_array( $curl, $options );
$content = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($content);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom); 

$tabless = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tbody'); 
$rows = $tabless->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr');

foreach ($rows as $roww) 
{ 

$colss = $roww->getElementsByTagName('td');

//$player = $cols->item(0)->nodeValue; $pstats[$i]['player'] = trim($player);
//$percentage = $cols->item(1)->nodeValue; $pstats[$i]['gamesplayed'] = trim($percentage);
$cricket = $colss->item(2)->nodeValue; $pstats[$j]['cricket'] = trim($cricket);
$o1 = $colss->item(3)->nodeValue; $pstats[$j]['01'] = trim($o1);


$j++;
}
```

Comment: Please show your current code, maybe someone can suggest how it can be changed. Rather than writing the code for you.

Comment: Do some research on "scraping HTML with PHP" ([here's a tutorial for example](http://wern-ancheta.com/blog/2013/08/07/getting-started-with-web-scraping-in-php/)) and see where you can get with writing the code yourself. Stack Overflow is for debugging, not for getting all the code written for you.

Comment: If they're changing their structure you'll have to make changes every time if they don't have some standardized JSON or XML you can access. If you think this will be the output they generate all the time, and there is no other reliable way to get their data, consider PHP's [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not saying whats being changed in the DOM, so it's hard to make a "always works" solution.

Heres a solution which parses the result in two stages. The first stage gets the data from the table, then the second stage requires at least 4 elements or it continues. It should be easy enough to debug if it changes again.

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents('...'));
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;

$pre = [];
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('table') as $table) {
    foreach ($table->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $i => $tr) {
        $y = 0;
        foreach ($tr->childNodes as $td) {
            $text = trim($td->nodeValue);

            if ($y > 7) {
                unset($pre[$i]);
                continue;
            }

            if (empty($text)) {
                continue;
            }

            $pre[$i][] = $text;
            $y++;
        }
    }
}

// normalise
$result = [];
foreach ($pre as $row) {
    if (count($row) != 4 || $row[0] == 'Team Totals:') {
        continue;
    }

    if (!is_numeric($row[1]) || !is_numeric($row[2]) || !is_numeric($row[3])) {
        // looks broke again, send email to developer ;p
        continue;
    }

    $result[$row[0]] = [
        'name' => $row[0],
        'games' => $row[1],
        'mpr' => $row[2],
        'ppd' => $row[3]
    ];
}

echo '<pre>'.print_r($result, true).'</pre>';

/*
Array
(
    ['Lawrence Cherone'] => Array
        (
            [name] => Lawrence Cherone
            [games] => 51
            [mpr] => 5.00
            [ppd] => 67.48
        )

    ['Scott Sandberg'] => Array
        (
            [name] => Scott Sandberg
            [games] => 51
            [mpr] => 4.02
            [ppd] => 33.18
        )

*/
?>
```

**To build a table from the result:**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <?php foreach (array_values($result)[0] as $key => $row): ?>
            <th><?= ucfirst($key) ?></th>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($result as $key => $row): ?>
        <tr>
            <?php foreach ($row as $row): ?>
            <td><?= $row ?></td>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Or to access the individual players stats:**

```
<?= $result['Scott Sandberg']['games'] ?>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You are awesome man, thank you very much...Tbh I am unsure of what was changed, I had it working for the last few days using node counts, and today when it was updated it threw the numbers all over the place. By looking at the updated sheet, I really don't see any changes besides the date....I think this checking for the 4 elements will work beautifully. One more thing if you don't mind, I am trying to echo the contents individually...This is a little new to me, so here is the way I am trying, which doesn't seem to work..

Comment: `if ($result->name == 'Josh Slom') {
 echo $row[2];
}`

Comment: You want it in a table?

Comment: I have a div for each player I would like to put their MPR, PPD etc under their name.

Comment: Cool, updated, see the bottom bit. Notice `$result[$row[0]]` change in the PHP bit.

Comment: Thank you so much, sir! I'm looking for a donation box on your website